# How to iterate the loop over a number of files using regex perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Input Filename: `AB_12_2_1324_01.xml & AB_12_2_1324_02.xml`
From input file i need to pickup the data such as:

```
<Filename="AB_12_2_1324_01">
<Filename="AB_12_2_1324_02">
```

Output file named as `AB_12_2_1114.xml` here data from input has to be appended in output and also the output has a new tag i.e 
    `<ID>1<\/ID>` followed by other data.

The problem where i am stucked is that the ID tag is not getting incremented, data from next file is not getting copied and it is getting printed in new line with unwanted space.

CODE:

```
foreach my $f (@xml) {

    #print F7 $f."\n";
    open( FH, "$path1\/$f" );
    my $data = join( "", <FH> );
    if ( $data
        =~ m/<Document id="(((\w+)_(\d+)\_(\d+))\_(\d+)\_(\d+))">/s )
    {
        my $name = $2;
        unless ( open FF, '>>' . "$path1\/$file" ) { }    #output file
        print FF "<ID>\d<\/ID>\n";
        print FF "<Name>(.*?)<\/Name>\n"
            ;    #tag taken for example from where data is getting copied.
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<ID>1<\/ID>

  A
  B
<ID>1<\/ID>

  A
  B
```

Output should be:

```
<ID>1</ID>
AB

<ID>2</ID>
CD
```

UPDATED CODE(THE CODE WHICH I AM USING):

Yes, the source file is xml.
Can someone please help me out with this code along with explanation if you don't mind..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Cwd;
use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;
use File::Find;
use Time::Piece;

my $path1=$ARGV[0];

print "Enter the weekday:";   my $week=<STDIN>;
print "Enter the date:";     my $dd=<STDIN>;
print "Enter the month in short:";  my $mmss=<STDIN>;
print "Enter the year:";   my $yy=<STDIN>;
print "Enter the time in HH:MM:SS:";  my $tt=<STDIN>;

my $pubdate=$week.",".$dd.$mmss.$yy."\t".$tt."\n";  #<pubDate>Sat, 25 Oct 2014 12:20:00        +0000</pubDate> here after Sat the data gets printed with unwanted space and also in newline.

opendir(INP1, "$path1\/");
my @xml = grep(/(\.xml|xMl|xmL|Xml|XmL|XML|XMl|xML)$/,readdir(INP1));   
close INP1;

foreach my $f(@xml)
{
open(FH, "$path1\/$f");
my $data = join("", <FH>);
my $xml_list=$data;
my $outfile;
my $Title;

if($xml_list=~m/<Document id="(((\w+)_(\d+)\_(\d+))\_(\d+)\_(\d+))" Num="\d+">/s)   #EF_13_2_0314_01
{
my $outfile=$2;
my $digit=$7;
if($digit=~m/(\d+)/s)
{
$digit=~s/^(0)//sg;
my $dig=$digit+2; #i incremented the digit by 2 when the filename is "AB_12_2_1324_01"

if($xml_list=~m/<Field Num="1" Label="Title">(.*?)<\/Field>/s)
{
my $Title=$1;
my $dates1 = localtime->strftime('%m%Y');
my $file = $outfile."_".$dates1.".xml";  #output filename

unless(open FF, '>>'."$path1\/$file"){}
print FF "<item>\n";
print FF "<title>$Title<\/title>\n";
print FF "<pubDate>$pubdate+0000<\/pubDate>\n"; #here before $pubdate and after unwanted space gets added as well as the data gets printed in new line.
print FF "<wp:post_id>$dig<\/wp:post_id>\n"; #here for first file $dig=3 and so on i.e if filename is AB_12_2_1324_01" post id should be 3 and so on.
print FF "<\/item>\n";
#print FF "<\/channel>\n";print FF "<\/rss>\n"; #this part should get printed in output at the end of the file when the entire xml file is being read and appended (say after file AB_12_2_1324_10.xml").
close FF;
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: This looks like you're XML parsing the hard, unreliable way. Is your source data XML? Could you post a fuller sample. I would suggest looking at XML::Twig and using that to extract the data you need.

Comment: Still need some sample input XML For a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```
 my $dir = getcwd();
 opendir(DIR, $dir) || die "Couldn't able to read dir: $!";
 my @xml = grep(/\.xml$/, readdir(DIR));
 closedir(DIR);
 my $i = '1';
 foreach my $f(@xml)
 {
    #print F7 $f."\n";
    open(FH, "$path1/$f") || die "Couldn't able to open: $!\n";
    local $/; $_=<FH>; my $data=$_;
    if($data=~m/<Document[^>]*id="(((\w+)_(\d+)\_(\d+))\_(\d+)\_(\d+))">/g) #If the Document id fixed formatted only
    {
        my $name=$2;
        open FF, ">>$path1/$file" unless("$path1/$file"); #output file
        print FF "\n<ID>$i<\/ID>\n";
        print FF "<Name>$name<\/Name>\n"; #tag taken for example from where data is getting copied.
    }
    $i++;
 }
```